# InternalResourceViewResolver to resolve both JSP and HTML together

Tags: spring-mvc

I want `org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver` to resolve both JSP and HTML pages.

Is that possible?

Comment: The InternalResourceViewResolver is mainly for resolving jsp but not html,    you can use ContentNegotiatingViewResolver, see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24838783/1165178).

Comment: Working solution
------------------
Please check the below link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24980839/spring-mvc-viewresolver-not-mapping-to-html-files

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can configure an `InternalResourceViewResolver` something like this:

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">

    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=""/>
</bean>
```

Where the `WEB-INF/pages` folder can contain both jsp and html pages and the suffix property is left empty.

Then in your controller, you can have methods that return html views and methods that return jsp views based on the suffix. For example, if `index.html` and `index.jsp` both exist in `WEB-INF/pages` you can do:

```
@RequestMapping("/htmlView")
public String renderHtmlView() {
    return "index.html";
}

@RequestMapping("/jspView")
public String renderJspView() {
    return "index.jsp";
}
```

However, as html pages are static and require no processing, you'd be better to use the `<mvc:resources>` tag rather than a view resolver for this type of page. See the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#mvc-config-static-resources) for more info.