# Spring Boot with Thymeleaf and AngularJS ui-router

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, angular-ui-router, thymeleaf

I am trying to create a simple Spring boot web application. i am using Thymeleaf and AngularJs for my front end.

everything works fine until I try to add ui.router in my application.

[image: below is my project structure]

below is my app.config:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
             $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

                $stateProvider        

                    .state('home', {
                        url: '/home',
                        template: index1.html
                    })
})
```

when i run my application, the partil "index1.html" is not loaded in ui-view.

i am getting error as "http://localhost:8080/index.html is bad request"

from my understanding the templateUrl is worng. please guide me in getting this right.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to let Angular UI router do the routing, you need to create a Spring Controller that accepts the route, but returns index.html.

Perhaps this answer can help also:
[Which spring view resolver plays nice with angularjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24838165/which-spring-view-resolver-plays-nice-with-angularjs)

Also [article](https://dzone.com/articles/thymeleaf-fragments-and) can help.