# How to redirect an url ending by ".jsp"

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot

I have a mapped url to `/foo.jsp` wich redirects to a controller, but it is not handled by spring and returns a 404. It seems that the url is ignored and directly send to tomcat. Is it possible to make spring handle it ?

To reproduce, starting from https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/1.4.x/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-tomcat7-jsp just add :

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addRedirectViewController("/foo", "/").setStatusCode(HttpStatus.MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
        registry.addRedirectViewController("/foo.html", "/").setStatusCode(HttpStatus.MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
        registry.addRedirectViewController("/foo.jsp", "/").setStatusCode(HttpStatus.MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
    }
}
```

Then navigating to `/foo` and `/foo.html` works as expected, but `/foo.jsp` returns a `404`

Comment: Using [UrlRewriteFilter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) I was able to redirect a jsp url, but the spring behavior feels buggy.

Answer (score 1):

Would you use a viewResolver to handle the jsp views.
And segregate html and jsp views differently using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24838783/6159397) technique.

Comment: We are in the process of migrating jsp/scriptlets to mvc, the whole point is to keep referenced url up by redirecting to the new one