# View not getting resolved in Spring mvc gradle application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

web application is made with gradle sts project
i've added view Resolver like this

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
   </bean>
```

it is hitting the url but wont return any view

@Controller
public class HomeController {

```
@RequestMapping(value = DatahubClientConstant.CLIENT_URL , method = RequestMethod.GET )
public ModelAndView getTestPage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        //System.out.println("Hello World");
    return new ModelAndView("home");
}
}
```

Tried to sysout it works

It doesnt return any view?

Comment: What's in container logs? Is there home.html in WEB-INF/views?

Comment: @ЮрийПлевако Плевакоyes their is home.html in WEB-INF/views

Answer (score 0):

After Some Research i have found out that **InternalViewResolver does not resolve html pages** directly that's why i was not able to get the view.

[Spring MVC ViewResolver not mapping to HTML files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24980839/spring-mvc-viewresolver-not-mapping-to-html-files)

This was a helpful question in resolving the issue. All it is doing is loading the html as static content.