# Why JSP don't convert into HTML?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, controller

Why JSP don't convert into HTML? so, I don't know what to show you

```
  @Bean
    public UrlBasedViewResolver urlBasedViewResolver(){
        UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        return resolver;
    }


@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/WEB-INF/views/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/views/");
}
```

One of my JSPs...

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Edit word</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="edit" method="post">        
    <input name="id" type="hidden" value="${id}">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

...

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/words/edit",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String editWord(Model model, @RequestParam(required = false) String userID){
    model.addAttribute("words",wordService.getAll());
    return "/words/edit";
}
```

Displays as just opened JSP in browser:
[image: That return my controller]

[image: structure of pages]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: Welcome, what is the result of the browser request ? An error, the jsp code, an other page ? If the last one, have you some 404 error management, htaccess, ... ?

Comment: @AxelH, That return for all my pages. please watch [that one of results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewH5t.png)

Comment: Ok well you don't ask to convert the jsp I think. Read this http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-redirecting . I am not a professional of this technology but this should do it

Comment: Just a note : I doubt you need the `/` in the name of the file `/words/edit` -> `words/edit`. That should resolve into /WEB-INF/views/ **words/edit** .jsp

Comment: @AxelH, and this variant I tired too..(

Answer (score 0):

Please return  "words/edit" instead of "/words/edit". You have already set resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/"); returning ""/words/edit" results in "//words/edit" .

Comment: I don't have edit.jsp in views folder. But i have then in views\words\. Please watch my [structure of pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZqNh.jpg)

Comment: I don't have edit.jsp in views folder. But i have **it** in views\words\.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that using a `UrlBasedViewResolver` will only redirect to the file but a JSP need to be parse/compile.

The doc of Spring tell you that there is `InternalResourceViewResolver` and `InternalResourceView` that internally forward the jsp file. This will parse the file as you need.

> For view technologies such as JSPs that are processed through the
>   Servlet or JSP engine, this resolution is usually handled through the
>   combination of InternalResourceViewResolver and InternalResourceView,
>   which issues an internal forward or include via the Servlet API’s
>   RequestDispatcher.forward(..) method or RequestDispatcher.include()
>   method.

Source :
http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-redirecting

Comment: unfortunately, but I tried to use as InternalResourceViewResolver and as InternalResourceView. The result is the same

Comment: @Виктор For a correct usage of these object, check existing answers :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24980839/spring-mvc-viewresolver-not-mapping-to-html-files