# Set up both .html and .jsp ViewResolvers in Spring 4?

Tags: java, spring, spring-4

If I need only `.jsp` as a view in my web application, then I write something like this:

```
 @EnableWebMvc
 @ComponentScan("com.test")
 public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

   @Bean
   public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
     InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
     resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
     resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
     return resolver;
   }
 }
```

Is it possible to use `.html` as well? For instance:

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {
  @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String printHello(ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!");
    return "hello"; // uses jsp extension
  }
}

@Controller
public class HomeController {
  @RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String home() {
    return "home"; // uses html extension
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [InternalResourceViewResolver to resolve both jsp and html together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20564336/internalresourceviewresolver-to-resolve-both-jsp-and-html-together)

Comment: The recipe is for xml configuration and doesn't work for me.

Comment: You could just write your configuration based on xml example, like in your case you need to convert it in to resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
     resolver.setSuffix(""); and mention extention while returning from your controller.

Comment: I did that. Doesn't work.