# Multiple suffix for viewResolver in Spring?

Tags: spring, tomcat

I want to include another suffix for viewResolver. How can I do that? For example right now it has the suffix value ".vm" but I also want to include ".vm.test". I tried creating another bean with the same ID and I got duplicate ID error.

```
    <bean id="viewResolver"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityViewResolver">
            <property name="cache" value="false" />
            <property name="prefix" value="" />
            <property name="suffix" value=".vm" />
    </bean>
```

Comment: then try use a different id

Comment: Tried id as viewResolver1 but the thing I was testing wasn't working. So I thought maybe it isn't the right way

Answer (score 0):

It will work fine for me. if your are looking for multiple suffix then instead of ***VelocityViewResolver*** you can use ***InternalResourceViewResolver***

In XML you can refer [InternalResourceViewResolver to resolve both JSP and HTML together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20564336/internalresourceviewresolver-to-resolve-both-jsp-and-html-together)

In Java config

```
@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver()
{
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    resolver.setPrefix("/resources/views/");
    resolver.setSuffix("");
    return resolver;
}
```